# Why do some applications ask the user if they follow daylight saving time?

Tags: date, time, timezone, dst

After allowing the user to select their timezone many applications ask if the DST adjustment should be made. Given resources like the [tz database](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database) which contain past and present information on DST observances for each timezone, why do applications ask?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They shouldn't.  Usually those that do are not using the tz database and have made invalid assumptions about how time zones work.

It is usually paired with a time zone selection dropdown that only lists numeric offsets, like this:

[image: bad tz selection]

One should instead consider asking for time zone like this:

[image: good tz selection]

By asking for countries first, one can reduce the choice of time zones from the tz database to just a handful for the country.  And since many countries only have a single time zone, sometimes the user will just need to select their country.

BTW - Both of the above graphics are from the Pluralsight course, [Date and Time Fundamentals](http://www.pluralsight.com/courses/date-time-fundamentals), of which I am the author.  I cover this issue, and many other similar common mistakes.

You can also read more in [the timezone tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info), in the section titled "TimeZone != Offset".

There is one common exception to this rule - Microsoft Windows.  If the chosen time zone has DST, then Microsoft allows a user the option to disable it:

[image: windows tz selection]

This is sometimes needed because there are places in the world that are not represented fully by the options Windows presents.   Microsoft doesn't use the TZ database for this, but has their own time zones that they maintain.

For example, if you live in [Atikokan, Ontario, Canda](http://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/canada/atikokan), the only valid selection in Windows is Eastern Time with DST disabled.  Compare that with the TZ database, which has defined a zone specifically as `"America/Atikokan"`.

This can create a problem for .NET developers, as `TimeZoneInfo.Local.Id` will return `"Eastern Standard Time"` regardless of whether the DST flag is turned on or off in the control panel.   However, if it's disabled, then all of the adjustment rules will have been stripped away.  In other words, `TimeZoneInfo.Local != TimeZoneInfo.FindBySystemId(TimeZoneInfo.Local.Id)`.   If the application just stores the ID, then it has no way to retrieve the time zone for somewhere like Atikokan.

Comment: +1 for predicting my next question which was why Windows gives the option.  I'm sure things are 10X more complicated than on the surface but it is funny that because Microsoft uses their own less complete database they allow the user to pick an option which in reality is already defined somewhere.  :)  Thanks for the course link too.  Finally - your comment about TimeZoneInfo.Local.Id returning "Eastern Standard Time" regardless of the user DST flag setting - it's just a nitpick but I want to be clear: I assume this behavior only matters (and is wrong) during DST season...?

Comment: "Eastern Standard Time" is the **ID** of the time zone.  It represents both EST and EDT *unless* you have the DST checkbox cleared.  Then the whole `TimeZoneInfo` object is stripped of its DST adjustment rules and just represents EST (without EDT).   It matters not just when it's *currently* DST, but any time you are working with dates that fall into the DST period.

Comment: [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org) makes it a lot easier, and gives you access to the tz database. :)